# getting Access Violation when trying to use injected IActionContextAccessor in tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to access the UrlHelper through IUrlHelperFactory and IUrlHelperFactory needs ActionContext.
I register both, but it results in IIS quitting with "Access Violation" message.

**IServiceCollection**:

```
.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>()
.AddSingleton<IUrlHelperFactory, UrlHelperFactory>();
```

**Tag Helper**:

```
private readonly IUrlHelper _url;

public ServiceIconTagHelper(IUrlHelperFactory url, IActionContextAccessor context)
{
    _url = url.GetUrlHelper(context.ActionContext);
}
```

**Output exception**:
The program '[1624] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: please post the full exception/logs

Comment: @DanielA.White sure. but it says just what I wrote. Access Violation

Comment: where are you seeing that? is there more context.

Comment: @DanielA.White no. I see that in the output window. The site starts up, get's to the tag helper and quits - leaving the above message in the output window

Comment: @DanielA.White I've changed to using LinkGenerator. It isn't an answer to the question so I leave it open

Comment: @DanielA.White after sone debugging I think it may have something to do with Authorization. But I can't figure out exactly what it is